# How to report a bug to Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I found the following error in a Mule 4 components. How can I report this issue to Mulesoft?

Mule 4 XML Module 1.2.3 introduced a bug that causes the wrong Mule error to be raised in the module.

When validating an invalid XML payload (non-xml string, "XML" with unclosed or unpaired tags, etc) version 1.2.2 of the component would raise mule error `XML-MODULE:INVALID_INPUT_XML`, but with version 1.2.3 of the component the error is now `XML-MODULE:TRANSFORMATION`.

The problem seems to be that version 1.2.3 of the module removed the call to `XMLUtils.toDOMNode`, which was used to do an initial validation of the message and threw exception of class `InvalidInputXmlException` when processing an invalid XML.

XML module : 1.2.2

```
public class SchemaValidatorOperation extends PooledTransformerOperation<SchemaValidatorOperation.SchemaKey, Validator> {
  private LSResourceResolver resourceResolver = (LSResourceResolver)new MuleResourceResolver();
  
  @Validator
  @Execution(ExecutionType.CPU_INTENSIVE)
  @Throws({SchemaValidatorErrorTypeProvider.class})
  public void validateSchema(@Path(type = PathModel.Type.FILE, acceptedFileExtensions = {"xsd"}) String schemas, @Optional(defaultValue = "W3C") SchemaLanguage schemaLanguage, @Content(primary = true) InputStream content, @Config XmlModule config) {
    Node node = XMLUtils.toDOMNode(content, this.documentBuilderFactory);
    withTransformer(new SchemaKey(schemas, schemaLanguage.getLanguageUri(), this.expandEntities), validator -> {
          validator.setResourceResolver(this.resourceResolver);
          final List<SchemaViolation> errors = new LinkedList<>();
          validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                public void warning(SAXParseException exception) {}
                
                public void error(SAXParseException exception) {
                  trackError(exception);
                }
                
                public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) {
                  trackError(exception);
                }
                
                private void trackError(SAXParseException exception) {
                  errors.add(new SchemaViolation(exception.getLineNumber(), exception.getColumnNumber(), exception.getMessage()));
                }
              });
          try {
            validator.validate(new DOMSource(node));
          } catch (SAXParseException e) {
            throw new TransformationException("Failed to validate schema. " + e.getMessage(), e);
          } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InvalidInputXmlException("Could not validate schema because the input was not valid XML. " + e.getMessage(), e);
          } 
          if (!errors.isEmpty())
            throw new SchemaValidationException("Input XML was not compliant with the schema. Check this error's Mule message for the list of problems (e.g: #[error.errorMessage.payload[0].description)", errors); 
          return null;
        });
  }
```

XML module : 1.2.3

```
public class SchemaValidatorOperation extends PooledTransformerOperation<SchemaValidatorOperation.SchemaKey, Validator> {
  private LSResourceResolver resourceResolver = (LSResourceResolver)new MuleResourceResolver();
  
  @Validator
  @Execution(ExecutionType.CPU_INTENSIVE)
  @Throws({SchemaValidatorErrorTypeProvider.class})
  public void validateSchema(@Path(type = PathModel.Type.FILE, acceptedFileExtensions = {"xsd"}) String schemas, @Optional(defaultValue = "W3C") SchemaLanguage schemaLanguage, @Content(primary = true) InputStream content, @Config XmlModule config) {
    withTransformer(new SchemaKey(schemas, schemaLanguage.getLanguageUri(), this.expandEntities), validator -> {
          validator.setResourceResolver(this.resourceResolver);
          final List<SchemaViolation> errors = new LinkedList<>();
          validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                public void warning(SAXParseException exception) {}
                
                public void error(SAXParseException exception) {
                  trackError(exception);
                }
                
                public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) {
                  trackError(exception);
                }
                
                private void trackError(SAXParseException exception) {
                  errors.add(new SchemaViolation(exception.getLineNumber(), exception.getColumnNumber(), exception.getMessage()));
                }
              });
          try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", this.expandEntities.isAcceptExternalEntities());
            spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", this.expandEntities.isAcceptExternalEntities());
            spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", !this.expandEntities.isExpandInternalEntities());
            spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", this.expandEntities.isExpandInternalEntities());
            validator.validate(new SAXSource(spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader(), new InputSource(content)));
          } catch (SAXParseException e) {
            throw new TransformationException("Failed to validate schema. " + e.getMessage(), e);
          } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InvalidInputXmlException("Could not validate schema because the input was not valid XML. " + e.getMessage(), e);
          } 
          if (!errors.isEmpty())
            throw new SchemaValidationException("Input XML was not compliant with the schema. Check this error's Mule message for the list of problems (e.g: #[error.errorMessage.payload[0].description)", errors); 
          return null;
        });
  }
```

Not that `XMLUtils.toDOMNode` was perfect since it catched any Exception, but at least it was useful to detect instances when trying to validate an incorrect xml.

XMLUtils.toDOMNode

```
public class XMLUtils {
  public static Node toDOMNode(InputStream src, DocumentBuilderFactory factory) {
    return toDOMNode(src, factory, null);
  }
  
  public static Node toDOMNode(InputStream src, DocumentBuilderFactory factory, EntityResolver entityResolver) {
    try {
      DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      if (entityResolver != null)
        documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(entityResolver); 
      return documentBuilder.parse(src);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new InvalidInputXmlException("Cannot parse input XML because it is invalid.", e);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

For open source components of Mule like the XML Module you can open a JIRA ticket in MuleSoft open tracker: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/projects/MULE. The sources for the XML module are at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-xml-module so you could attach a push request to the ticket if you create one.

If you are a current customer of MuleSoft you can engage their Support directly.